# Beamer - Pauses in a Line in Non-Linear Way

Tags: beamer, pause

I am currently using Beamer, and I would like to show an expression in a weird way.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    }
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{block}{Title}
We have $1 \leq A \leq B \leq C \leq 2$
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

The equation $1 \leq A \leq B \leq C \leq 2$ I would like to appear in the following way:

1) $1 \leq C \leq 2$

2) $1 \leq A \leq C \leq 2$

3) $1 \leq A \leq B \leq C \leq 2$

I know this is obviously a weird way to present an expression (though it does make sense in context of my presentation). But is there any way to make it appear this way whilst presenting?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! How about `We have $1\only<2->{ \leq A}\only<3->{ \leq B }\leq C \leq 2$` ? (Please do not forget `\begin{document} and `\end{document}` in code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Why do you think this is weird?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] %<- frame does not jump
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{block}{Title}
We have $1\only<2->{ \leq A}\only<3->{ \leq B }\leq C \leq 2$
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]